# How do I mask output in transformer model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mask, transformer-model

I am applying the transformer model and I apply padding_mask + look_a_head_mask to the attention layer. But the masks are not propagated to outputs. Is there any way to apply padding_mask when calculating loss?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate any loss and add it with `add_loss()` or you can do backpropagation directly in custom loop